# Conversion of acetaldehyde to butane-1,4-diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

How to convert acetaldehyde (ethanal) to butane-1,4-diol. I just tried doing aldol, but it leaves an alkyl group at the end. Also it cannot be done by oxidizing ethane with basic permanganate.

[image: Ethanal to dihydroxybutane]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! As this appears to be a homework-type of question, I suggest reading through [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) discussion. The more work and effort you can show, i.e. writing out possible reaction mechanisms, etc., the better. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. Cross Aldol and add H+
   [image]

[image]

2. Oxidise Aldehyde to Carboxylic Acid

use any of the reagents

[image]

[image]

3.Perform Arndt–Eistert reaction

[image]

[image]

4. Use LiAlH4 for reduction of acid to alcohol

[image]

And finally you get 1,4-dihydroxybutane.

Image courtesy Wkipedia, SigmaAldrich